# Group cohomology with $Z_2$ coefficient

Tags: group-cohomology, at.algebraic-topology

I would like to know what are the group cohomology classes $H^d[Z_n, Z_2]$,   $H^d[U(1), Z_2]$, $H^d[SO(n), Z_2]$, $H^d[SU(n), Z_2]$, etc. Thanks!
(Here the group cohomology $H^d[G, M]$ for a group $G$ is the topological cohomology of the classifying space $BG$, $H_{top}^d[BG, M]=H^d[G, M]$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the latter three, here is the integer-coefficients (apply Kunneth formula to get your mod-2 coefficients:

[Group cohomology of compact Lie group with integer coeffient](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75389/group-cohomology-of-compact-lie-group-with-integer-coeffient)

As for the first:  $H^i(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ is $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for $i$ even, and zero otherwise.  Again, apply Kunneth formula for $\mathbb{Z}_2$-coefficients.

In general, for a finite group $G$,  $H^*(G,M)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_{|G|}$-module for $n>0$.  And If $M$ has exponent $p$ (prime) then $H^*(G,M)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-vector space.  So for $gcd(n,2)=1$ we must have $H^*(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_2)=0$ (in positive dimensions).

Comment: Dear Chris:
Kunneth formula relates $H^*[G_1\times G_2, M]$ to $H^*[G_1, M]$ and $H^*[G_2, M]$. I do not know how Kunneth formula relates $H^*[G, Z_2]$ to $H^*[G, Z]$.


Comment: .... No, it relates $H^*(G_1\times G_2,M\otimes M')$ to $H^*(G_1,M)$ and $H^*(G_2,M')$.  Take $G_2=0$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $M'=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: (flip the M and M' entries around actually; but I guess the typo is evident)